# Finding parameter values in a parameterized polynomial using Viete's formula

Tags: polynomials

Function:

$$ f(x) = x^2 + mx + x + 1 $$

is given. It has two different zeroes and their sum squared is equal to $$ 3m + 5 $$ The goal is to calculate all values of the m param that would satisfy that condition.

First step was to calculate $\Delta$:
$$\Delta = m^2 - 4 $$
$$\Delta = (m - 2)(m + 2)$$
$$m_0 = 2$$
$$m_1 = -2$$

Then apply the Viete's formula to the condition:

$$(x_1 + x_2)^2 - 2x_1x_2 = 3m + 5$$

After substitution:

$$ (-m)^2 - 2 = 3m + 5$$
$$ m^2 - 3m = 7$$

And I don't know where to go from here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misread the term for $x$ in the quadratic. You should write $$f(x)=x^2+(m+1)x+1$$
Then $x_1+x_2=-\frac ba=-(m+1)$. You already found that $x_1x_2=1$, so $$x_1^2+x_2^2=(m+1)^2-2$$
You are also given that $x_1^2+x_2^2=3m+5$.
We then get $$m^2+2m+1-2=3m+5$$ or $$m^2-m-6=0$$
The solutions are $m=-2$ and $m=3$. The $m=2$ solution yields complex roots for the initial equation, since $x_1^2+x_2^2=3(-2)+5=-1$.

Comment: I didn't misread the term :) The task says the function is like I wrote above :) Also, I'm pretty sure there shouldn't be any complex roots, because it's from highschool math course. But maybe the task itself is formulated wrongly then?

Comment: Maybe I did not correctly explained what I had in mind: the $mx+x$ part of your function can be written as $(m+1)x$. There is no need to change the function itself. You just want to write it in the form $ax^2+bx+c$. Then $a=1$, $b=m+1$, and $c=1$

Comment: Ah, now I get it :)

Answer (score 0):

You found $m_0=2, m_1=-2$ and assumed that $\Delta=0$. This means that you assumed that your quadratic has equal roots which contradicts the condition of different zeroes that you gave earlier.

Otherwise, it is perfectly correct. you finally arrived at the relation $m^2-3m-7=0$. Just solve for $m \in \mathbb{R}$.

Additionally, if your question said "two different **real** zeroes" then an additional condition $\Delta >0$ would have been imposed.

Comment: I don't think I understand first two of your sentences :) Could you please elaborate? Did I calculate something incorrectly?

Comment: Also the answer sheet says $ m = 3 $ and I don't get that result if I solve that last quadratic.